# 000 Webhost Actions after payment

Tags: php, mysqli, paypal, phpmyadmin, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to do a payment with paypal. When I work on my local machine and run the code, payment goes through and after that it redirects to my "pago.php" file. This one has the SQL queries to insert into my orders table and deleting the items from the Cart. While working on localhost, payment goes through and tables update correctly.

Now I've uploaded my project to a hosting site (000 Webhost) and for some reason payments go through, I get redirected to my website and payment gets confirmed, however for some reason, the SQL queries don't execute.

I've tried reducing it to a simple query to only delete, but doesn't even do it. Here's the PHP code after redirecting:

```
<?php


include '../includes/db.php';
include '../acciones/sesion.php';





$cookie = $_COOKIE['mTotal'];
$uid = $row['id'];
$username = $row['usuario']; 



$transaccion = $_GET['tx'];
$resultado = $_GET['st'];
$monto = $_GET['amt'];
$clientId = $_GET['cm'];

if($cookie == $monto && $resultado = 'Completed' && $clientId = $uid){
    $sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM carro where idCliente = '$uid'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            $productId[] = $r['idProducto'];
            $cant[] = $r['cantidad'];
            $nombre = $r['nombreProducto'];
            $precio[] = $r['precio'];

            $prodArray = array($productId);
        }

        $q = $con->query("SELECT * FROM direccion WHERE idCliente = '$uid' and main=1");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0){
            while($r2 = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
                $idDir = $r2['idDir'];
            }
        }

        for($i=0; $i < count($productId); $i++){
            $con->query("INSERT INTO `comprafinalizada` (`compraId`, `clienteId`, `productoId`,  `cantidad`, `monto`, `transaccionId`, `FechaCompra`, `idDireccion`) VALUES (NULL, '$uid', '".$productId[$i]."', '".$cant[$i]."', '".$precio[$i]."', '$transaccion', current_timestamp(), '$idDir')");      
        }

        $con->query("DELETE FROM carro WHERE idCliente = '$uid'");

    }


}

    

?>
```

I've tried changing apostrophe's, removing the cookie confirmation and just running the DELETE query. Not sure why this code is not running, and I'm not sure if this has to do with me using the Paypal sandbox.

I hope I can get some help here. Thanks

Comment: If you want help please use proper formatting.

Comment: What you need is an IDE, not the notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in this line:

```
if($cookie == $monto && $resultado = 'Completed' && $clientId = $uid){
```

you are assigning 'Completed' to variable $resultado and not comparing it. If you want check if `$resultado` has the value `'Completed'` use double equals signs like `$resultado == 'Completed'`

Same with `$clientId = $uid` should be `$clientId == $uid`.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my life, that was part of the problem, I started noticing also that $cookie and $uid are not being captured. Thanks for your help